# Why is TimeUnit a member of java.util.concurrent?

Tags: java

Java's `TimeUnit` enum is useful for many different tasks related to time, not just concurrency; and other time-related classes like `Date` are part of `java.util`.  So why is `TimeUnit` a member of `java.util.concurrent`?

Comment: I think it was introduced to make calls to methods like `Condition.await()` easier.

Comment: Because it was added when some of the new nio concurrency was added and thus is in that package. Although it does serve as a nice time enum for general time things like calendar you should use Joda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As well as providing methods to work with different granularities of time, TimeUnit provides Thread-aware methods like [timedJoin](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#timedJoin%28java.lang.Thread,%20long%29):

`public void timedJoin(Thread thread,
             long timeout)
               throws InterruptedException`

I think the class originated to help with common concurrent programming tasks like delayed execution. As it stands it has two distinct functions (manage time granularities; apply temporal concepts to threading problems), which violates the [single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Given the utility and popularity of TimeUnit outside concurrent code, a neater solution could be a `java.util.TimeUnit` enum to manage time granularities and a separate `java.util.concurrent` class for its applications in threading.

Answer (score 5):

It is probably there for historical reasons:

- the legacy date API has not evolved much over the past few years
- `TimeUnit` is widely used in the concurrency utilities

Interestingly, the new date API in Java 8 has a [`ChronoUnit` enum](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) which is similar to the `TimeUnit` enum, but applied to dates and times. In particular, a `ChronoUnit` can be converted to a `Duration`.

Answer (score 2):

`TimeUnit` was developed by the Concurrency expert group for the concurrency utilities primarily. Such libraries are often developed using a typical 3rd party package outside the `java.`... packages to allow testing with existing JVMs. Later they are integrated by renaming the packages. So it is a historical reason, mostly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is more of a design decision. They added it when they needed it for concurrency. Hence, they put it under the concurrent package. Yes, we can use it even when concurrency is not involved. But it was a necessity in concurrent applications. Well, I can be wrong.

"A [TimeUnit](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) represents time durations at a given unit of granularity and provides utility methods to convert across units, and **to perform timing and delay operations** in these units."

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is because they wanted to write intuitive code for concurrency. The `TimeUnit` JavaDoc says:

> A TimeUnit is mainly used to inform time-based methods how a given timing parameter should be interpreted. For example, the following code will timeout in 50 milliseconds if the lock is not available:
>
> ```
>    Lock lock = ...;
>    if (lock.tryLock(50L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) ...
> ```

So, I guess that they were writing the Lock class, and wanted such a way to specify time. For that reason, they created an auxiliary class `TimeUnit` which was originally only intended to use for their Lock code and friends. Over time, it probably got abused for general purposes.

The JavaDoc for the `java.util.concurrent` says:

> Utility classes commonly useful in concurrent programming.